# Past Continuous Tense usages

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which of the following is a usage of the past continuous tense?

1. Action in progress at a specific time in the past. **(Correct)*
2. A completed past action
3. An action that was completed before a past time.
4. An action that began in the past and continues up until the present time.

I got this question wrong and selected 4. Can someone explain why the correct answer is 1? To me, it doesn't seem right since we can write non-specific sentences like "he was cooking".

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Please let me know if my answer satisfies you.  If it does not, please send me some feedback, and I would be happy to clarify anything or edit my response.

Answer (score 1):

An example of the usage in (1) is:

> He was **still playing** videogames **after midnight last night.**

The action (playing videogames) was in progress (still playing) at a specific point in the past (after midnight last night).

*You can't just say "he was playing videogames," you need to have a specific time.  Otherwise, you would use the simple past ("he played videogames").*

(4) describes the present perfect and present perfect continuous.
For example:

> He **has watched** 100 hours of TV **this week.**

The action (watching TV) started in the past (at the beginning of the week) and is continuing into the present (*this* week is still occurring).

> He **has been watching** TV **for a few hours;** he should take a break. [continuous]

The action (watching TV) started in the past (a few hours ago) and is continuing into the present (*implicit*).